# Get array of Facebook users from ids

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to keep track of people my users invite to my app via Facebook. 
I'm using the iOS Facebook SDK and when inviting via the request `"me/invitable_friends"` you get a list of friends for the user who haven't downloaded your app yet.. However, you only get their Facebook ids after you invite them.

i.e.

I have 4 invitable friends

```
Fred
Joe
John
Sally
```

I invite John and Sally and I'm returned their facebook ids... so I'd like to remove them from the invitable_friends list, but I don't know who's id is which.

So I have

`John`
`Sally`

With some unknown relationship to 2 ids

`12345678`
`67891011`

Obviously with a small set I could call the graph equivalent of  `https://www.facebook.com/12345678` and find out who is who... but as the max number of invites count stands at 50.. It'd be so much better if I could bulk this into one call and get an array of details back... Is there a graph api call like this? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question basically just is, how can you request data for more than one id at a time?

That is described in the documentation chapter about basic API usage, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#multiidlookup

You can specify multiple ids via the `ids` parameter – `/?ids=12345,67890,…`

Comment: Cheers CBroe. My searching skills are clearly lacking when it comes to fbgraph.